# Ffmpeg using encoder HVEC_AMF outputs a low bitrate when the bitrate is fixed

Tags: ffmpeg, video, graphics-card

I decided to write a program to connect multiple videos and audio.

I have an AMD graphics card, I want to use `hvec_amf` (to use the h265 codec).

when I write video codec in the code like a `-c:v hvec_amf`, then the specified video bitrates do not work via `-b:v` ( `-b:v 4500k -minimum speed 4500k -maximum speed 4500k` ), and I get a finished file with a bitrate of ~350-400 kb/s. FFMPEG version is 5.0 (last)

This is the full command I've ran:
`fmpeg -i "intro_1.mp4" -i "intro_2.mp4" -i "rjaved.mp4"  -i "rjaved.mp3" -i "outro.mp4" -y -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][3:a][4:v][4:a] concat=n=4:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -codec:v  hevc_amf   -b:v 4500k  -minrate 4500k  -maxrate 4500k -vsync 2  -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 192k  -minrate 192k  -maxrate 192k  "output.mp4`

[all data on the source files in the form of a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXQ2F.jpg)

[screenshot of video processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z6UB.jpg)

.

**My Computer Specs:**

```
Processor - Intel Xeon E5 2689,
RAM - 48 GB ECC REG DDR3 1600 MHz,
Graphics PROCESSOR - AMD RADEON RX 580 8 GB,
Memory capacity > 2 TB,
The computer has the latest AMD drivers (22.3.1)
```

Comment: idk the solution to your issue, but… why fixed bitrate? That will make it waste space in simple scenes yet be unable to keep up in complex ones.

Comment: set v or a at -minrate and -maxrate. ```fmpeg -i "intro_1.mp4" -i "intro_2.mp4" -i "rjaved.mp4"  -i "rjaved.mp3" -i "outro.mp4" -y -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][3:a][4:v][4:a] concat=n=4:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -codec:v  hevc_amf   -b:v 4500k  -minrate:v 4500k  -maxrate:v 4500k -vsync 2  -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 192k  -minrate:a 192k  -maxrate:a 192k  "output.mp4```

Comment: I second @Tetsujin statement. Better to use variable bitrate, which is set by default

Comment: For getting help about the codec, execute: `ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_amf`. There is an option to set constant bitrate: Try adding the argument `-rc cbr`

Comment: When using the "-rc cqp" parameter, the bitrate increases, but the final version is obtained with about a bitrate of 1500 kb/s, but I have sources with a bitrate of 4000 kb/s and more. I don't know what to do.